# "Type 'SqlClient.SqlConnection' is not defined" despite having System.Data namespace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to use `SqlClient` classes in Visual Studio Code to get a data from a SQL Server table. However, when I try to put the following into a function, I get the error

> Type 'SqlClient.SqlConnection' is not defined.

Code:

```
    Dim con As String = "server=[...];"
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT [...]"
    Try
        Dim rtn As New DataSet
        Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(con)
            conn.Open()
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Using da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(rtn)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return rtn
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
```

I used the recommended action of adding `System.Data.` to the front, but when I replace `SqlClient.SqlConnection` with `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, I get a new error:

> Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' in assembly 'Lab Machines Display, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Either a reference to 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is missing from your project or the type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' is missing from assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Other details: I am currently using the .NET 6.0 framework. I can see that I have `System.Data` in my namespaces, though I cannot see what version it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out on my own. Apparently, .NET removed the option to use SqlClient, so I went into "Manage NuGet Packages", searched "system.data" under browse, then installed the System.Data.SqlClient package.